# Resume AVAudioPlayer when other app is done playing

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer

I am using AVAudioPlayer to play audio in background. When other app such as WeChat is playing a voice message, my app pauses audio playing, but when the voice message stops playing, my app doesn't resume audio playing.

My audio session is set as follows:

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: AVAudioSession.Mode.default, options: [AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.allowBluetoothA2DP])

AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
```

I tried to add observer for `AVAudioSession.routeChangeNotification` and check whether other app is playing audio with the `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().isOtherAudioPlaying`. But the notification is only sent when other app started to play an audio, but not when they're done, so I can't resume playing when other app is done.

Comment: Did you register for the interruptions notification?

Comment: @matt Just tried it and it worked. Thanks! :)